# Get WordPress title without the_post

Tags: wordpress

I need to loop through a set of posts before the main content in a page template. That's easy:

```
$getCoverArticles = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'cover',
        ),
    )
);

$queryCoverArticles = new WP_Query( $getCoverArticles );

if($queryCoverArticles->have_posts() ) {
  while($queryCoverArticles->have_posts() ) {
    $queryCoverArticles->the_post();
    ?>
        <a><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php
  }
}
```

Problem is, the method sets the global post object, so trying to get `the_content()` after this loop gives the content for the last post in the loop...

Seems a bit extreme to juggle around the global post object just for a title property. Is there a way to easily get at the title without assigning it as the global object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

> **Note:** If you use [the_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post) with your query, you need to run [wp_reset_postdata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) afterwards to have [Template Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) use the main query's current post again.

So:

```
if($queryCoverArticles->have_posts() ) {
  while($queryCoverArticles->have_posts() ) {
    $queryCoverArticles->the_post();
    ?>
        <a><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php
  }
}

// Restore original post data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

... should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add `wp_reset_postdata();` just after you're done with the extra query and the query should be restored so that the global $post refers to the current post in the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following code, I hope this will works for you.

```
<?php

if ($queryCoverArticles->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $queryCoverArticles->have_posts() ) : $queryCoverArticles->the_post();
        ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a><br /><?php
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```